# Searchbox control crashes on typing faster or lengthy queries in Windows 8.1 Store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, search-box

I am trying to implement Searchbox with search suggestions. Every time i type in faster or a lengthy query text the app is crashing. The exception is not getting caught in the catch block.

```
private void SearchBoxEventsSuggestionsRequested(object sender, SearchBoxSuggestionsRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    try { 
        var pList = GetPList();
        string queryText = e.QueryText;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryText))
        {    
        Windows.ApplicationModel.Search.SearchSuggestionCollection suggestionCollection = e.Request.SearchSuggestionCollection;
        foreach (var p in pList)
        {
            bool exists = p.desc.IndexOf(queryText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1;
                                if (exists)
                                {

                                    string result = p.desc + Environment.NewLine + p.name;
                                    suggestionCollection.AppendQuerySuggestion(result);
                                }
        }
        }                                            
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}                
}
```

The GetPList method is not async.

what am i getting wrong here?

Comment: First of all, why is your function async? You have nothing to await.

Comment: that was a mistake. No async keyword used.

Answer (score 0):

You may try a delay approach. Wait for a second before any other key press. Once user has stopped typing, then you may perform the search/filtering.

Start a timer and perform your operation in the Tick. If there is another key press immediately. Reset the timer, so that the Tick is delayed further.